# Which of the following word is matched to the sentence?

Tags: word-choice

I have a question with 4 options, I would like to know if what I chose is correct.

> "The lecture was so **...** that almost everyone fell asleep."

1) bored
2) dull 
3) exhausted 
4) tired

I chose option number 2 (dull), because all the rest are make the verbs passive and then they can not cause to active action of felling asleep. My choosing is correct?

Comment: _Dull_ although in everyday language people say _boring_. It's not a good question since if someone doesn't know the meaning of dull, he can simply rule out all other options since other adjectives describe an animate being and lecture is definitely not one.

Comment: The answer is correct, but not the "why". Numbers 1), 3) and 4) are adjectives. And so is 2) but it describes the lecture, whilst the other adjectives are used to describe the effect something has on us. E.g I was bored by the movie = The movie was boring.

Comment: @Mari-LouA +1 but a good example of the "worthy of an answer?/closeworthy?" conundrum. How "elementary" is "too elementary?" When is a good answer in a comment appropriate?

Comment: @P.E.Dant yes, spot on re. conundrum. But if a newcomer wants to post an answer, they're welcomed to. I suspect this type of question must have been asked before.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yup, I consciously averted my eyes from duplicates...

Answer (score 1):

A lecture can not be

> bored
>   tired

since a lecture is not animate.

A lecture might be

> exhausted
>   *the lecture was exhausted*
>   *the possibilities were exhausted*

which might mean it has come to its end, but

> so exhausted

is not possible since this might describe the physical state of a lecture.

> The lecture was so *dull* that almost everyone fell asleep.
>   The lecture was so *boring*...
>   The lecture was so *exhausting*...
>   The lecture was so tiring...
>
> The students were so *bored* that almost everyone fell asleep.
>   The students were so *tired*...
>   The students were so *exhausted*...

are all possible and correct.

> The students were so *dull* that almost everyone fell asleep.

though grammatically correct, may not make sense logically.